# Jquery finding the prev element with same class across dom

Tags: jquery, dom-traversal

One more question on superior jQuery

I want to find a dom element with class say,abc, when i click on an element with same class. Now the search should be exactly the previous element.

Code i have written:

```
$(this)
    .closest('.abc')
    .parent()
    .prevAll()
    .find('.abc')
    .first()
    .triggerHandler("focus");
```

This is searching back the parent's previous dom and searching abc, but if the class 'abc' doesnt exist in previous dom, i want to search until it finds abc, Also tried with prevuntil of jquery still no luck.

If anyone can help me out, many thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful to include your HTML to see your DOM tree.

Comment: dom tree is complex and specific, i want a generic solution.

Comment: If the class does'nt exist in previous DOM, you'd like to keep on searching, but where exactly is it you would like to search, some other DOM ?

Comment: @abhi Well, those 5 chained functions don't seem too generic to me. It's quite specific for a certain DOM tree.

Comment: The above code never leaves the parent level, so I'm sure you can synthesize some HTML to describe the problem even if your full HTML is more complex

Comment: @bazmegakapa you right mine code isnt generic, i was looking for generic solution. thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this to get the previous element:

```
var $current = $(this); //the element you have
var $elems = $('.abc'); //the collection of elements

var $previous = $elems.eq($elems.index($current) - 1); //the one you needed
```

- [jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pg7RL/1/)
- [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/)

I would not say this is the most efficient code possible, but without knowing the DOM tree, that's the best I can come up with. If you only rerun `$('.abc')` when the DOM might have changed and only use the cached version (`$elems`) it should be fine.

Comment: Much nicer than my ugly loop! +1

Comment: thats what i was looking for bu am asking the same question you have asked to me if the class doesnt it?? Thanks so much for your time, let me evaluate this as per my needs and would keep you posted and post my answer soon or if this works would mark as an answer. Thanks

Comment: @abhi Sorry, I don't understand your problem.

Comment: +1 and accepted, i tried this approach but yours is a killer and generic, thanks sir.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty way:

```
$('.abc').click(function(){
    var clicked = this;
    var last;
    // Go though all elements with class 'abc'
    $('.abc').each(function(){
        if(this == clicked) return false;
        last = this;
    });
    if(last) $(last).triggerHandler("focus");
});
```

Comment: Oops, example updated, it had a serious problem. See working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/TKZz8/

Comment: very nice thanks for the answer, i used the above as that is less with looping, +1.